# Why doesn't the v-menu work with v-btn when the v-btn has v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've been trying to implement a v-menu on a v-btn that as v-for. It works fine without v-for. I'm retrieving the category name using axios. So dont mind that. I just want the v-menu to work like that.

```html
    <div class="text-center">
              <v-menu
                :close-on-content-click="false"
                :nudge-width="200"
                offset-x
              >
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                 
                    <v-btn
                      color="indigo"
                      dark
                      v-bind="attrs"
                      v-on="on"
                      :value="categoryid"
                       v-for="(categoryItem, i) in categoryList" :key="i"
                      @click="subcat(categoryItem._id)"
                    >
             
                      {{ categoryItem.cname }}
                    </v-btn>
                 
                </template>

                <v-card>
                  <v-list>
                    <v-list-item>
                      <v-list-item-avatar>
                        <img
                          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/john.jpg"
                          alt="John"
                        />
                      </v-list-item-avatar>

                      <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>
                        <v-list-item-subtitle
                          >Founder of Vuetify</v-list-item-subtitle
                        >
                      </v-list-item-content>

                      <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-btn icon>
                          <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                      </v-list-item-action>
                    </v-list-item>
                  </v-list>

                  <v-divider></v-divider>

                  
                </v-card>
              </v-menu>
            </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `v-for="(categoryItem, i) in categoryList" :key="i"` because that key is useless. Use `v-for="(categoryItem, i) in categoryList" :key="categoryItem._id"`

Comment: Please give more detail about your problem. Are any errors displayed in the console?

Comment: Using an index as a `v-for` `:id` isn't useless, just *less* useful. If one item leaves the list, all items thereafter will be rerendered since the indexes of all subsequent items will all change. Since it looks like you've got access to `._id` on your items, then by all means use that unless there's some other reason you're refraining.